# Alter result for map in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Since map will return "undefined" for elements not matched what is the best way to return only those that match?

```js
let items: string[] = ["false", "false", "true"];

let newItems: string[] = _.map(items, function(item) {
  if (item === "true") {
    return "newItem";
  }
});

console.log(newItems);
// newItems = [undefined,undefined,"newItem"];

let filterItems: string[] = _.filter(items, function(item) {
  if (item === "true") {
    return "newItem";
  }
});

console.log(filterItems);
// filterItems = ["true"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

I could use _.filter however filter would return the value of "true" instead "newItem" as I need it.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I for sure don't mind the down votes but would like to understand why it is down voted. Please leave a message to understand what needs to be updated or corrected.

Comment: So many great answers but one must be chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**reduce**](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) to do both operations at the same time:

```
let items: string[] = ["false", "false", "true"];

let newItems: string[] = _.reduce(items, function(memo, item) {
  if (item === "true") {
    memo.push("newItem");
  }
  return memo;
}, []);
```

```js
let items = ["false", "false", "true"];

let newItems = _.reduce(items, function(memo, item) {
  if (item === "true") {
    memo.push("newItem");
  }
  return memo;
}, []);

console.log(newItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should `filter` then `map`, that way you are only calling `map` over matching items

```
let newItems: string[] = _.map(
   _.filter(items, function(item) {
      return item === "true";
   }),
   function(newItem) {
      return "newItem";
   }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use both map and filter:

```
collection.filter(it => it === 'true').map(it => 'newItem');
```

There's nothing wrong with returning `undefined` when you can't `map` a value, but you don't want those in the final result, so just `filter` then out.

Your concern about `filter` returning a boolean and not a transformed value is just how filter is supposed to work. It returns the original values that pass the test function, so you can map (or any other functional operation) on the subset.